# Angular/webpack not looking for .d.ts file in @spartacus/storefront

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, spartacus-storefront

This is a question for the SAP Spartacus team.

While creating a Spartacus component, I have come across errors where specific Spartacus `.d.ts` definition files cannot be resolved.

The issue is reproducible in the following Github repo/branch:
https://github.wdf.sap.corp/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/tree/module-import-issue/storefront

The issue is not happening for all Spartacus definitions, just some.

When I use the following import statement in our component code, `tsc` can compile the code without issue (the file `/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.d.ts` exists):

`import { CmsComponentData } from '@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data';`

But when I run `ng serve --verbose` I can see that angular/webpack are not probing for it. The probing is just checking for files with a `.ts` extension, but not a `.d.ts` extension:

```
WARNING in [DedupeModuleResolvePlugin]: /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/core/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js -> /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js

ERROR in ./src/app/cms-epd-visual.model.ts

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data' in '/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/src/app'

resolve '@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data' in '/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/src/app'

  Parsed request is a module

  using description file: /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)

    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

    resolve as module

      looking for modules in /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront

        using description file: /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/package.json (relative path: .)

          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

          using description file: /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/package.json (relative path: ./@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data)

            no extension

              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data doesn't exist

            .ts

              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.ts doesn't exist

            .tsx

              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.tsx doesn't exist

            .mjs

              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.mjs doesn't exist

            .js

              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.js doesn't exist

            as directory

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data doesn't exist

      /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/src/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

      /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

      /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

      /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

      /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

      /Users/i070295/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

      looking for modules in /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules

        using description file: /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)

          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

          using description file: /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/package.json (relative path: ./cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data)

            no extension

              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data doesn't exist

            .ts

              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.ts doesn't exist

            .tsx

              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.tsx doesn't exist

            .mjs

              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.mjs doesn't exist

            .js

              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.js doesn't exist

            as directory

              /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data doesn't exist

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.ts]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.tsx]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.mjs]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.js]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/src/app/node_modules]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/src/node_modules]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/node_modules]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/node_modules]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/node_modules]

[/Users/i070295/node_modules]

[/Users/node_modules]

[/node_modules]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.ts]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.tsx]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.mjs]

[/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.js]

 @ ./src/app/cms-epd-visual.model.ts 1:0-101 4:47-63

 @ ./src/app/epd-visual.component.ts

 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts

 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts

 @ ./src/main.ts

 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-node ./src/main.ts
```

I have seen a hack/workaround suggested on the web which is to change the import path to include a .d suffix to attempt to fool the module loading mechanism to treat a `.d.ts` file as a `.ts` file, but this does not work with angular 10.1 which rightly points out that 3rd party libraries should include definition files, not uncompiled `.ts` files:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model/cms-component-data.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview).
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:949:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/Users/i070295/SAPDevelop/vis/commerce-cloud-poc/storefront/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:43:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
 @ ./src/app/cms-epd-visual.model.ts 1:0-103 4:47-63
 @ ./src/app/epd-visual.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-node ./src/main.ts
```

I have also tried the following import statement which doesn't work:
`import { CmsComponentData } from '@spartacus/storefront/cms-structure/page/model';`

The issue is specific to particular Spartacus definition files.
If I remove the usage of `CmsComponentData` and instead import and use the following type in exactly the same place in the code, I do not see any issue:

`import { B2cStorefrontModule } from '@spartacus/storefront';`

Can anyone provide any suggestions as to what I can do to avoid this issue?

Best regards,
Sam Garland

Answer (score 0):

This import statement works:
`import { CmsComponentData } from '@spartacus/storefront';`